# How can I get my smiley button to open the popup I've created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find the problem, I've tested out the button with an alert tag. The button is possible and works fine, it was styled and transparent with CSS, so that's out of the way. But it seems I just can't get it to open the popup I've created through JavaScript and HTML. What do you guys think?

To skip straight to the code environment.
  [Click this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEwEJj)
`<div class="popScroll"><div class="popup"> 
  <!-- Smiley button -->
<button onclick="alert('hi');" class="smiley"><!--<div class = "smiley"></i></div>--></button>
  <!--Ribbon-->`

I'm fairly new so indentation of my code is restricting me from posting the javascript, but it's on the link. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: You need to load jQuery. Something like this should be in your .html file `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I've included this in my HTML and removed the alert, but still out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You Need To Link **Jquery Script** ...

Attach files **jquery-2.1.x.js** with containing folder

or get it from 
https://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling a JavaScript alert function directly into the HTML, you do not need to put quotation marks around the alert, just the text that you are trying to get it to put into an alert.  It should look something like

If you have quotation marks around the word alert it will treat it as a pre-existing function that it will call from the script.

Comment: The alert is just a test button on the popup. I'm trying to open the popup in the center with the smiley face. Should I forward the alert to the same tag of the popup?

Comment: You could also use a JavaScript event listener.  The code would be something like document.getElementById("Smiley").addEventListener("click", function() {alert("Hi");});

Comment: Read more about Event Listeners at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp ,http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp, or http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp.